# Shiny: select axis and groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny app whit dynamical variables choice.

My data is quite simple:

```
structure(list(condition = c("id_0.2cov_0.0evalue_0.001", "id_0.3cov_0.0evalue_0.001", 
"id_0.4cov_0.0evalue_0.001", "id_0.5cov_0.0evalue_0.001", "id_0.6cov_0.0evalue_0.001", 
"id_0.7cov_0.0evalue_0.001", "id_0.8cov_0.0evalue_0.001", "id_0.9cov_0.0evalue_0.001", 
"id_1.0cov_0.0evalue_0.001"), min = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), max = c(14342, 11393, 2084, 605, 599, 332, 312, 87, 27), 
    mean = c(140.048780487805, 54.4480442512841, 13.275661095323, 
    3.88437742230991, 3.06546546546547, 2.34792609062332, 1.80316779085515, 
    1.38615434908341, 1.0040692315819), sd = c(678.649173146197, 
    264.996993952984, 48.1297686832552, 10.8809910787991, 7.88905730023133, 
    5.24114778761008, 3.328441395118, 1.64173750197931, 0.0878496418628203
    ), sum = c(275616L, 275616L, 275616L, 275616L, 275616L, 275616L, 
    275616L, 275616L, 275616L), n = c(1968L, 5062L, 20761L, 70955L, 
    89910L, 117387L, 152851L, 198835L, 274499L), rep = c(0.00714036920933473, 
    0.0183661325902705, 0.0753258156275398, 0.257441512829444, 
    0.32621473354232, 0.425907784743992, 0.554579559967491, 0.721420381980727, 
    0.995947259955881), dif = c(273648L, 270554L, 254855L, 204661L, 
    185706L, 158229L, 122765L, 76781L, 1117L), identity = c(0.2, 
    0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

So the app is also quiet simple:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Cluster summary"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
          "selectedX",
          "Select colum for X axis",
          choices = colnames(clu.summary[-1]),
          selected = colnames(clu.summary[-1])[2]
        ),
        selectInput(
          "selectedY",
          "Select colum for Y axis",
          choices = colnames(clu.summary[-1]),
          selected = colnames(clu.summary[-1])[3]
        ),
        selectInput(
          "selectedG",
          "Select colum for Group",
          choices = colnames(clu.summary[,c(1,10)]),
          selected = colnames(clu.summary[,c(1,10)])[2]
        )
      ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")) )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x_axis <- input$selectedX
    y_axis <- input$selectedY
    gcolor <- input$selectedG
    gg <- ggplot(clu.summary, aes(x=x_axis,y=y_axis)) + 
            geom_point(aes(color=gcolor)) + 
            geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    gg
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is what I'm getting
[image]
Generate by this code `gplot(clu.summary, aes(x=colnames(clu.summary[-1])[2], y=colnames(clu.summary[-1])[3])) + geom_point(aes(color=colnames(clu.summary[,c(1,10)])[2])) + geom_smooth(method="lm")`

but what I'd like to get is something like this:
[image]
Generated by this code `ggplot(clu.summary, aes(x=max, y=mean)) + geom_point(aes(color=identity)) + geom_smooth(method="lm")`

Anyway, both code should be the same since:

```
> colnames(clu.summary[-1])[2]
[1] "max"
> colnames(clu.summary[-1])[3]
[1] "mean"
> colnames(clu.summary[,c(1,10)])[2]
[1] "identity"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like this?

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x_axis <- input$selectedX
    y_axis <- input$selectedY
    gcolor <- input$selectedG
    gg <- ggplot(clu.summary, aes(x=get(x_axis),y= get(y_axis))) + 
      geom_point(aes(color=gcolor)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    gg
  })
})
```

Comment: So tiny detail... rsrsrs Thanks a lot